# How to calculate avg # of inputs needed for an outcome if different outcomes change the probability?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I'm not sure if I worded the question well or not, but here's my situation.

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the average number of instances needed to reach state 3, starting at state 0.

State 0

- 65% chance of staying at state 0
- 15.75% chance of moving to state 1
- 10.5% chance of moving to state 2
- 8.75% chance of moving to state 3

State 1

- 65% chance of staying at state 1
- 26.25% chance of moving to state 2
- 8.75% chance of moving to state 3

State 2

- 65% chance of staying at state 2
- 35% chance of moving to state 3

I'm using this for a random chance to get different tiers of treasure upon clearing a level, and I want to make sure that you don't have to clear levels a ridiculous number of times, and avoid frustration from getting a treasure worse or equal to what you already have. I tried to find a calculator or simulator for this, but I can't find anything anywhere, and I don't know how to calculate this myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you studied Markov Chains and/or stopping times?

Answer (score 0):

Denote $\operatorname{E}_n$ the expected number of steps to go from state $n$ to state $3$. We are interested in $\operatorname{E}_0$. Now we can set up the following recurrence equations:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}_0 & = 1 + 0.65\operatorname{E}_0 + 0.1575\operatorname{E}_1+0.105\operatorname{E}_2 \\
\operatorname{E}_1 & = 1 + 0.65\operatorname{E}_1 + 0.2625\operatorname{E}_2 \\
\operatorname{E}_2 & = 1 + 0.65\operatorname{E}_2 \\
\operatorname{E}_3 & = 0
\end{align}

($\operatorname{E}_3$ is not really needed, but included for clarity). Solving for $\operatorname{E}_0$, I get $5.96429$. So you need on average roughly $6$ instances to get from state $0$ to state $3$. A small simulation is in excellent agreement with this analytic result (the `R` code for the simulation is at the bottom of the answer).

You could also employ the machinery of Markov chains, as illustrated in my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450305/expected-number-of-tosses-until-winner-in-game-with-two-players-with-two-differe). What you're looking for is called mean absorption time starting from state $0$. Your transition matrix is:

$$\mathbb{P} = \pmatrix{0.65 & 0.1575 & 0.105 & 0.0875 \\ 0 & 0.65 & 0.2625 & 0.0875 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.65 & 0.35 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}$$

The [fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix) is $\mathbf{N}=(\mathbf{I}_3 - \mathbf{Q})^{-1}$, where $\mathbf{I}_3$ is an identity matrix and $\mathbf{Q}$ is the $3$-by-$3$ transition matrix of the non-absorbing states. In your example:

$$
\mathbf{N} = \pmatrix{2.857143 & 1.285714 & 1.821429 \\ 0 & 2.857143 & 2.142857 \\ 0 &  0 & 2.857143}
$$

The [expected number of steps to absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps) when starting in transient state $i$ is the $i$th entry of the vector
$$
\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{N}\mathbf{1}
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is a length-$t$ column vector with all $1$s. Applied to our example we get:
$$
\mathbf{t} = \pmatrix{5.964 \\ 5.000 \\ 2.857}
$$
This confirms the result from above.

In `R`, there is the convenient package `markovchain` that simplifies these calculations for you:

```
library(markovchain)

# Transition matrix
tm <- matrix(c(0.65, 0.1575, 0.105, 0.0875,
               0, 0.65, 0.2625, 0.0875,
               0, 0, 0.65, 0.35,
               0, 0, 0, 1), 4, 4, byrow = TRUE)

# Initialize new markov chain
mcGame <- new("markovchain", states = as.character(0:3), transitionMatrix = tm)

# Calculate mean absorption time
meanAbsorptionTime(mcGame)

       0        1        2 
5.964286 5.000000 2.857143
```

The variance of the number of instances could also be of interest. We get it by the following formula:

$$
\left(2\mathbf{N} - \mathbf{I}_{3}\right)\mathbf{t} - \mathbf{t}\circ\mathbf{t}
$$
where $\circ$ denotes the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (element-wise product). For the example this evaluates to:

$$
\pmatrix{15.81 \\ 10.82 \\ 5.31}
$$

Starting at state $0$, the variance of the number of steps until reaching state $3$ is $15.81$. Again, this is in excellent agreement with a simulation.

Finally, here is the `R` code for the simulation with $100\,000$ repetitions:

```
set.seed(142857)
res <- replicate(1e5, {
  x <- c()
  while(!("3" %in% x)) {
    x <- rmarkovchain(n = 50, mcGame, t0 = "0", include.t0 = FALSE)
  }
  which.max(x %in% "3")
})

mean(res)
[1] 5.95455
var(res)
[1] 15.80432
```